# Split view controller at non root position IOS

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

Hi I am new to IOS development. I am developing small application I want to use split view. But that split view is not my root view. My application start with login which is not split view. After login I want to start my main view which is split view controller. So here is my problem if I set main view as root view i.e. start point for my application it works fine. But If I set my login controller as root controller then it gives exception. In my AppDelegate I am setting following things:

```
   UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    SidePannelViewController *controller = (SidePannelViewController *)masterNavigationController.topViewController;
    controller.splitViewController = splitViewController;
    splitViewController.delegate = (id)controller;
```

once I set my main view as root controller it works fine. How to solve this problem? Need Help. I want to keep my login screen as normal login view controller and after login start split view controller. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can present the LoginScreen as modal over the top of the split view controller, else you can initially set LoginScreen as rootViewController and then replace with SplitViewController as rootController.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
}
```

Once user logged in successfully dismiss the loginscreen.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replay. But can you please explain how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `LoginViewController` as the root view controller when the user is not logged in and changed the root  to split view if the user is logged in. Just put the check in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method to check if the user is logged in or not and set your root accordingly.